# listing open files from shared folders

Tags: samba4, microsoft-office, vfs

I have a Filer Server running Debian Jessie 8.7 on my network, with Samba 4.2.14.

Until now, I just have one shared folder configured for the entire network and I would like to watch if there are open files on this share.

---

- When running `smbstatus -L`, it doesn't point any information about any **open files** or **locked files**.

  ```
  $  smbstatus -L
  Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE
  Registered MSG_REQ_DMALLOC_MARK and LOG_CHANGED
  No locked files
  ```
- Using `lsof`, it only gives me the information about what process is using the shared on folder, on the local filesytem of the server.

  ```
  $ lsof | grep backup
  smbd      1432      root  cwd    DIR     8,9     4096       2 /backup/local
  ```
- Also using `fuser`, it doesn't give any information about **open files** or **locked files**. It just show the sPID which is using the shared folder on the local filesytem of the server.

  ```
  $ fuser /backup/local
  /backup/local:  1432c
  ```

---

There are some other options to track open files like:

- With a Shellscript, list all files with extensions like **.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx**, and so on, and make a `if [ -f ".~lock.new_document.docx#" ] ; then` in order to define if a Microsoft Office file is opened or not, but this of workaround, is not what I'm looking for.
- Using [VFS Modules](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/VFS.html) for auditing operations for any file inside the shared folder could be a source for a Shellscript, but that its not practical.

---

Is there anyone that could possibly know any tools that could list open/locked files from Samba shared folders, since that `smbstatus -L` doesn't seem to be an option for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my findings, thanks to **VFS Modules**, Samba does not keep File Descriptors for the files which are being shared and used, no matter what kind of normal file it is, with just one exception.

The only situation which I found that open files are visible via `lsof` or `smbstatus -L`, is when you have open files from **Microsoft Office 2010** onward.

```
$ lsof | grep bkp
bash      1272      root  cwd       DIR      8,9         4096     651521 /bkp/local/John
smbd      2492      root  cwd       DIR      8,9         4096          2 /bkp/local
smbd      6127      root  cwd       DIR      8,9         4096          2 /bkp/local
smbd      6127      root   35r      DIR      8,9         4096     651521 /bkp/local/John
smbd      6127      root   36r      DIR      8,9         4096          2 /bkp/local
smbd      6127      root   37r      DIR      8,9         4096          2 /bkp/local
smbd      6127      root   38r      DIR      8,9         4096          2 /bkp/local
smbd      6127      root   41r      DIR      8,9         4096          2 /bkp/local
smbd      6127      root   42r      DIR      8,9         4096     651521 /bkp/local/John
smbd      6127      root   44uR     REG      8,9            0     651529 /bkp/local/John/word_john.docx
lsof      6345      root  cwd       DIR      8,9         4096     651521 /bkp/local/John
grep      6346      root  cwd       DIR      8,9         4096     651521 /bkp/local/John
lsof      6347      root  cwd       DIR      8,9         4096     651521 /bkp/local/John
```

```
$ smbstatus -L
Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE
Registered MSG_REQ_DMALLOC_MARK and LOG_CHANGED
Locked files:

Pid    Uid    DenyMode  Access      R/W      Oplock     SharePath     Name                     Time

6127         1001       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE        /respaldo/segeco_local   .   Tue May 30 14:10:14 2017
6127         1001       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE        /respaldo/segeco_local   .   Tue May 30 14:10:14 2017
6127         1001       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE        /respaldo/segeco_local   .   Tue May 30 14:10:14 2017
6127         1001       DENY_WRITE 0x12019f    RDWR       LEVEL_II    /respaldo/segeco_local   Susana/word_susana.docx   Tue May 30 14:10:38 
2017
6127         1001       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE        /respaldo/segeco_local   Susana   Tue May 30 14:14:25 2017
6127         1001       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE        /respaldo/segeco_local   Susana   Tue May 30 14:14:25 2017
```

The same does not happen when you have, for example, a .docx file opened via **Microsoft Office 2007** or **LibreOffice 4**.

---

What usually happens (forgetting the situation above about the files from Microsoft Office 2010 onward: once a Client Machine, opens a file from a shared folder maintained by Samba, this file is cached on the file system of the Client Machine, an closed on the file system of Server.

Below, I described some observations which I have noticed during my experiments with **VFS Modules for Samba**.

The configuration for this functionality which allows to audit operations performed on every shared folder, is described at the end of my answer.

---

For Text Documents, Images, PDFs, Media Files, the **Client Machine**:

- opens the file
- caches the data
- closes the file on the local file system of the **Server**
- when saving modifications, **Samba** creates a temporary file on the **Server**
- when closing the file, **Samba** removes the original file and renames the tmp file to the name of the original file.

**opening file on Client**

```
May 30 11:13:02 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|r|Expedientes.txt
May 30 11:13:02 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|close|ok|John/Expedientes.txt
```

**saving file**

```
May 30 11:16:52 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|w|~gvfPvwn.tmp
May 30 11:16:52 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|pwrite|ok|John/~gvfPvwn.tmp
May 30 11:16:52 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|close|ok|John/~gvfPvwn.tmp
May 30 11:16:52 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|unlink|ok|John/Expedientes.txt
May 30 11:16:52 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|rename|ok|John/~gvfPvwn.tmp|John/Expedientes.txt
```

**closing files**

> Samba does not record operations for files that are closed on the Client Machines.

---

For Microsoft Office files (.docx, .doc, .xls, .xlsx, etc.), the **Client Machine**:

- opens the file
- caches the data
- closes the file on the local file system of the **Server**
- opens a tmp/lock file (.~lock.my_word_document.docx#) and closes it
- every byte inserted on the **Client Machine**, generates open/close ops on the original file
- when saving the file, the **Client Machine** writes the modifications into the file
- when closing the file, **Samba** removes the tmp/lock file

**opening file on Client**

```
May 30 11:22:14 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|w|Desktop Word John.docx
May 30 11:22:14 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|close|ok|John/Desktop Word John.docx
May 30 11:22:14 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|r|Desktop Word John.docx
May 30 11:22:14 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|w|.~lock.Desktop Word John.docx#
May 30 11:22:14 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|close|ok|John/.~lock.Desktop Word John.docx#
```

**writing data into the file (every written byte, generates OPEN/CLOSE ops)**

```
May 30 11:22:44 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|r|Desktop Word John.docx
May 30 11:22:44 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|close|ok|John/Desktop Word John.docx
May 30 11:22:44 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|r|Desktop Word John.docx
May 30 11:22:44 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|close|ok|John/Desktop Word John.docx
May 30 11:22:45 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|r|Desktop Word John.docx
May 30 11:22:45 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|close|ok|John/Desktop Word John.docx
```

**saving file**

```
May 30 11:26:33 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|w|.~lock.Desktop Word John.docx#
May 30 11:26:33 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|pwrite|ok|John/.~lock.Desktop Word John.docx#
May 30 11:26:33 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|close|ok|John/.~lock.Desktop Word John.docx#
May 30 11:26:33 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|r|Desktop Word John.docx
May 30 11:26:33 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|close|ok|John/Desktop Word John.docx
May 30 11:26:33 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|w|Desktop Word John.docx
```

**closing file**

```
May 30 11:37:39 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|open|ok|r|.~lock.Desktop Word John.docx#
May 30 11:37:39 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|close|ok|John/.~lock.Desktop Word John.docx#
May 30 11:37:39 server001 smbd_audit: normal.user|192.168.1.67|win7pc|serversharedfolder|unlink|ok|John/.~lock.Desktop Word John.docx#
```

---

If you are planning to implement the **VFS Modules for Samba**, here are some links which can guide you through the setup (don't forget to install the package `samba-vfs-modules`):

- https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/VFS.html
- https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/vfs_full_audit.8.html

Here is an excerpt from `smb.conf`, showing the setup of the feature for an specific shared folder:

```
...
[fileserver]
path = /bkp/local
valid users = john, jane, martin, carl
force group = sambashare
create mode = 0660
directory mode = 0770
available = yes
read only = no
writable = yes
browsable = yes
hide files = /lost+found/ 
vfs objects = full_audit
full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
full_audit:success = mkdir rename rmdir pwrite write unlink open close
full_audit:failure = mkdir rename rmdir pwrite write unlink open close
full_audit:facility = local7
full_audit:priority = warning
...
```

Don't forget to add an statement on `rsyslog` in order to generate data from the shared folder into a log file:

```
$ grep local7 /etc/rsyslog.conf 
local7.*            /var/log/samba/audit.log
```

Comment: What Office suite do you use? On Office2010 and Office2013 and Samba 3.6 (from a CentOS 6 x86-64), I see a very different behavior: the client keeps the file open, as clearly shown by `lsof`. Moreover, saving the edited file will *not* overwrite the original file, rather the new one is saved with a temp name and renamed.

Comment: Good one! I'm using Microsoft Office 2007 and I also tried with LibreOffice. I'll verify with another Office suite. Sounds interesting.  Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to monitor your filesystem activity using `inotifywait`

Comment: Yeap. I know the tool and it's very useful. I'll make an update on my answer. Thanks @shodanshok!